# java - can a certificate be verified with root CA or grand-parent CA without parent CA

Tags: java, security, certificate, ca

I am trying to do this in Java but I think it is a general certificate question. 
I have a root CA, an intermediate CA1 issued by root CA, an intermediate CA2 issued by intermediate CA1, and a certificate issued by the intermediate CA2.

rootCA -> interCA1 -> interCA2 -> cert

Is it possible to verify cert with interCA1, without knowing interCA2?

```
cert.verify(interCA2.getPublicKey()); // ok
interCA2.verify(interCA1.getPublicKey()); // ok
cert.verify(interCA1.getPublicKey()); // NOT ok -> is there any way to fix or bypass this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this because interCA1 is not the issuer of cert.

```
cert.verify(interCA1.getPublicKey());
```

A certificate is signed with the private key of the issuing certificate, so you need its public key to verify the signature. Therefore, to verify cert it is needed the complete certification chain.